# Android app showing in Google Play for Phone but not for Google Play for Tablets

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, google-play-services, tablet

The app is showing for Phones but not for Google Play for Tablets. 
Here is the Manifest code.

package="com.samplecode.app"

```
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="1.1" >         

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8"  
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Have you read and followed the Google's recommendations for tablets: https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html

Comment: Basically im not from tech background, im trying to add the code that shows the app in "Google Play for Tablets".

Answer (score 0):

1. Add 7" and 10" screenshots to your application description on Google Play.
2. Remove `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, because most of tablet have not got GSM module

   **OR**

   try to add this `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />`

   [Look this about hardware requirements](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements)

Comment: With this manifest file and adding 7 and 10'' screenshots of the app will the app show for "Google Play for Tablets" or there are any changes needed in the manifest file?

Comment: @Johnson I upadated my answer

Comment: added and checking the app in tablet